# Redefine @ for tabular inter-column specification within \makeatletter \makeatother

Tags: tables, tex-core, catcodes, ampersand

I need to use a `tabular` with a @ inter-column specification within a `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` environment. I. e. I something like

```
\makeatletter
%code that uses @ as letter
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
%code that uses @ as letter
\end{tabular}
%more code that uses @ as letter
\makeatother
```

Is there any alternative to the @-character in the tabular definition. For example the `\\` sequence can be substituted by `\tabularnewline` if necessary. Is there something similar for the @. And as I am already asking, does an alternative for `&` (in tabulars) exists, too?

Amendment from 21.06.2014:

I found a working solution myself. This is my code now:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myarticle}[2014/06/18 My article]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[paper=a4,fontsize=10pt,ngerman,hyperref,draft]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{textcomp} % required to get special symbols
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[final]{microtype}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter

\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage\null\noindent%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{lr}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}%
\sffamily
\Huge\@title\par%
\vskip.5ex%
\Large\@date\par%
\end{minipage}%
&%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}%
\raggedleft\footnotesize
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo.pdf}\par%
\vskip.5\baselineskip%
Company Name\par%
\vskip.5\baselineskip%
Street and Number\par%
Postal code and Town\par%
\end{minipage}%
\end{tabular}%
\par
}

\makeatother
```

Originally, I did not have the line

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```

but tried

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}r}%
```

instead to supress the inter-column spacing. The latter results into non-compiling code. So my guess was that the `@` notation interferes with the `\makeatletter` command.

Comment: It would have been helpful to have provided an example making an error. If you think there was a problem to which this is the solution please don't put the solution in the _question_ put it as an _answer_ and accept it.

Comment: I would not call it a solution but rather a work-around. As I wrote I wanted to use `@{}` to suppress the inter-column spacing. That did not work. Hence, I use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` now instead. In this particular situtation this is fine. But if one wanted to use `@{foo}` for anything else, e.g. to insert a vertical line between the columns, the `@`-notation still fails. Hence, the original question is still open.

Comment: Please make a _minimal_ example that _shows the problem_. "fais" is not at all informative, gives wrong output or gives error or ...

Answer (score 7):

The test for `@` is not sensitive to catcode so you do not need to do anything (but you shouldn't really need to use `\makeatletter` mid document).

For `&` you can use `\let\tabsep=&` in the preamble and use `\tabsep` instead of `&`.

Comment: Thanks, but I would not ask if `@` was working.Why do you believe I use \makeatletter in the middle of the document? I didn't write that, did I? I am writing a *.cls file based on `scrartcl` and I need to redefine \maketitle, hence I need to access \@title, \@date and so on. I need the tabular to layout the title.

Comment: @user2690527 something may not be working and your tabular may be on the class file not mid document (in which case your question is misleading as there is presumably no `\makeatletter` in the class file)  but as you did not provide any example code people have to guess. If if isn't working it isn't because of an interaction of \makeatletter and the tabular @ construct.